# Making DB Browser for SQLite run SpatiaLite queries

Tags: spatialite, sqlite

I've started using [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) and I liked its interface. However, even though I can open SpatiaLite databases in there, I can't use any spatial function while running queries from there.

My assumption is that I'd probably have to load the SpatiaLite module in the first line of my query in order to make `DB Browser for SQLite` use spatial functions. A related question is [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/84829/173457). I thought that using something like `select load_extension('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspatialite.so.7');` would solve this issue (the libspatialite.so.7 is a file that exists on my system). But although it seems to load the module successfully, when I try to use spatial functions like:

```
select load_extension('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspatialite.so.7');
select asText(geometry) from mytable;
```

I receive the error:

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: no such function: asText
At line 2:
select asText(geometry) from mytable;
```

Why can't I use SpatiaLite functions inside `DB Browser for SQLite`?

Comment: Best test for seeing if spatialite is available is probably `select spatialite_version();`.

Comment: @user30184 In my case, using `select spatialite_version();` works fine when I use it inside spatialite-gui, but it doesn't work inside DB Browser for SQLite after using `select load_extension(...);`... I'm probably getting the wrong file, I've searched for the files named `spatialite.so` on my system and the one from my question is the one that appeared. If spatialite is using a file that is not named `spatialite.so` as a module, I'm not sure how can I search for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure you're not running a sandboxed version ([snap](https://snapcraft.io/docs/system-files-interface) or [flatpak](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html)), install it from your distribution repositories instead. Sandboxed apps can't see the real `/usr/lib` directory (e.g. when accessing `/usr/lib`, snap apps are actually accessing `/snap/{app name}/current/usr/lib`).

In sqlitebrowser Preferences - Extensions tick the last checkbox "Allow loading extensions from SQL code"

Use [`mod_spatialite.so`](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=mod_spatialite) not `libspatialite.so.7`

```
select load_extension('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mod_spatialite.so');
select spatialite_version();
```

You don't even need the full path:

```
select load_extension('mod_spatialite');
select spatialite_version();
```

5.0.1

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Additional Info for Windows users: all files from "mod_spatialite-5.0.1-win-amd64.7z" (including "mod_spatialite.dll") available at [gaia-gis.it](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-amd64/) must be in the same directory as DB Browser for SQLite.exe (not in "extensions")